# ValueError: Can't handle mix of continuous and multiclass

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I want to estimate the model from the data I've used [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15vmZ4y9jwxtNkZYIZVyqBt_vbS0UDh_vEc2_b39lztw/edit?usp=sharing) in scikit-learn. I am using the `DecisionTreeClassifier.score` function but when running the code I'll receive an ValueError:

> Can't handle mix of continuous and multiclass.

Here is the code I use:

```
from sklearn import datasets
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
nba = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\nba.xlsx")
X = nba.drop('平均得分', axis = 1)
y = nba['平均得分']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
X, y, test_size = 0.20)
nba_tree = DecisionTreeClassifier()
nba_tree.fit(X_train, y_train.astype('int'))
y_pred = nba_tree.predict(X_test)
nba_tree.score(X_test, y_test)
```

Comment: Hi Hank, Google docs gives loading error. In addition, Chinese is fine on Chinese websites. Is it possible to change the chars into readable English?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your target variable `平均得分` is a continuous variable. Probably you are try to solve a regression problem. If that is the case then try [DecisionTreeRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html) instead of DecisionTreeClassifier.